# Why is hackerrank saying that my output is incorrect?

Tags: c++

I was completing the hackerrank 30 days of code chalenge day 6.

However when I submitted the code it said that i had the wrong answer despite it being the same as the expeected answer.

Does anyone know why this is happening and if i am doing anything wrong? I have also tested it with vvarious other IDE's and I received the same output.

Input:
2
Hacker
Rank

Expected output:
Hce akr
Rn **a**k
Actual output:
Hce **A**kr
Rn ak

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    for (int i = 0; i <x; i++){
    string s;
        string s1;
        string s2;
        cin >> s;

            for (int oddoreven = 0; oddoreven <= s.length(); oddoreven++  ){

                if (oddoreven%2==0){

                    s1 += s[oddoreven];
                }
                    else {
                        s2  += s[oddoreven];


                    }
                    
         }
         cout << s1 << s2 <<endl;
 
    }

   
    return 0;
    
    
 }
```

Comment: What is the hacker rank question as such

Comment: *"Expected output: Hce **a**kr Rn ak Actual output: Hce **A**kr Rn ak"* - There, I highlighted it for you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately your question does not meet our community requirements. Please do not be offended and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In the final iteration of the loop `oddoreven = s.length()`. `s[s.length()]` is undefined behavior. Presumably you're printing a NUL byte or so, which only shows up if you hex-dump the output of your program.

Change the condition in your loop to `oddoreven < s.length()`.